# How to login github in cmd?

Tags: windows, authentication, github, cmd, repository

I need to change directory from this directory to my git hub account, like : (my name) (my repository), I set global email and global username but it didn't work, please help me

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You should make a new folder and locate it, on the local machine. Then you should make a pull from the remote repository you are mentioning with the help of the following command,

`git pull <remote url>`

and you can set it.

To check out your `username` and `email` you can use the following command

```
git config user.name
git config user.email
```

In order to change or set the global `username` and  global `email` you can use

```
git config --global user.name "Name"
git config --global user.email "mail@xyz.com"
```